# prove that $(a,b)$ divides $(a+b,a-b).$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

In this problem, can I assume $(a,b)=1$? Otherwise I have
let $d=(a+b,a-b)$. Then $d \mid  ((a+b)+(a-b))$ which implies that $d \mid 2a$. Similarly, $d \mid 2b$.
Therefore, $d \mid (2a,2b)$.

From here, I'm lost.

Comment: If you assume that $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then it won't make for a very challenging problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $d = (a,b)$, then we have $a=da'$ and $b=db'$, where $(a',b')=1$. Then we have: $(a+b,a-b) = (d(a'+b'),d(a'-b')) = d(a'+b',a'-b')$. Hence the proof.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you implying that (a'+b',a'-b') is an integer? And so, (a+b,a-b)=dm, with m=(a'+b',a'-b') ?

Comment: @user370590 Yeah. The gcd function always yields an integer.